36 number roulette simulation in python
I'm trying to create a roulette simulator where I can bet on at least 10 numbers i.e 0.50 cents on a number, and if said number hit I get a x 36 on my money, I also want it to show my balance when it hits. But so far I can only get it to bet on one number. I would appreciate any help
this is what I have so far
import random

balance = 100

def start():
    global balance
    print("place your bet!: ")
    bet = int(input(">"))
    if bet > balance:
        insufficient_funds()
    else:
        simulate(bet)

def insufficient_funds():
    print("oops not enough money bucko")
    start()

def simulate(bet_amount):
    global balance
    print("choose a number between 0-36: ")
    answer = input("> ")
    result = random.randint(0, 36)
    if result == answer:
        print ("You won")
        balance = bet_amount * 36
        print(f"your balance is now{balance}")
        start()
    else:
        print ("you lost")
        balance -= bet_amount
        print(f"your balance is now {balance}")
        start()

start()


input returns a string of characters. You are comparing to integers from randint. This will never be True

Notwithstanding the comment by @PeterWood you have also inadvertently coded an inappropriate recursion

You would need a better data structure to accommodate multiple bets. Let the user input multiple numbers and store them e.g. in a list, or a dictionary if you want to be able to place different bets on different numbers. Then spin the wheel only when the user indicates they are done placing bets. A while True: loop is a better solution than the tangled recurson pointed out in a previous comment.

(A proper roulette game would also let you bet on red vs black, odd vs even, and various number ranges.)

How do you know it doesn't work? [edit] the question to describe what you think the code should be doing, and what it's actually doing, and identify the part you don't understand. See how to create a [mcve].

What is the question?

If you want the user to be able to enter multiple numbers, just ask for the numbers in a for loop and then add the numbers to a list. Then, when you are checking if the numbers are correct, compare the items in the list to the actual number. This looks like:
import random

answer_list = []
balance = 100

def start():
    global balance
    print("Place your bet: ")
    bet = int(input("> "))
    if bet > balance:
        insufficient_funds()
    else:
        simulate(bet)

def insufficient_funds():
    print("Oops, not enough money, bucko.")
    start()

def simulate(bet_amount):
    global balance
    print("Choose a number between 0 and 36: ")
    for count in range(0, 36):
        answer = input("> ")
        answer_list.append(int(answer))
    result = random.randint(0, 6)
    num_correct = False
    for count in range(0, len(answer_list)):
        if result == answer_list[count]:
            print("You won!")
            balance += bet_amount
            print(f"Your balance is now {balance}")
            num_correct = True
            start()
    if not num_correct:
        print("You lost.")
        balance -= bet_amount
        print(f"Your balance is now {balance}")
        print(f"The answer was {result}")
        start()

start()

I also don't know why you're making the balance variable change to the bet times 16 every time, so now the code just adds the bet into the balance without multiplying anything.

The first for loop is asking 36 times for input, independently of the number chosen, and it's 36 times assigning a random number to result without using it.

Also, if there's only one correct result, what's the sense of iterating through every number in the list of chosen numbers? I have never played a roulette... are you allowed to bet many times the same number?

What if I want to bet different amounts of money to different numbers?
